# a proof of contradiction

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

I am wondering whether the following is a valid proof?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very well-written, good job! I have a minor thing to point out.

When it comes to divisibility proofs, I would avoid fractions as much as possible and just stick to the integers. Notice that after you show that
$$
4y = -2 + x^2
$$
for some $y \in \mathbb Z$, you can immediately say that $4 \mid (x^2 - 2)$. There is no need to divide each side of the equation by $4$.

Comment: cool! I will fix them! thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. Although, "if $x$ is odd then $x^2-2$ is odd and therefore not divisible by 4" is rather quicker.

Comment: yeahh i just realized it. Thanks!